# Custom fields in post later used in loop

Tags: themes, loop, get-template-part

How i can add custom fields to custom post templates, and later print them in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

Better explanation: I want to have a custom field in "Add New" window, which will be added as some meta data to the post, which can be later printed in the loop of single.php.

I want to be able to decide where it will be, so it can be even under comments if i want to (i want to define it in template).

I dont want "Custom Field Template" plugin because AFAIK this cannot be used inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`get_post_custom()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) in The Loop, to retrieve an array with all custom fields for a post. In order to fetch a single field, you can use [`get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) with the third argument set to `TRUE`.

Comment: How to add those custom meta data to post?